# How to type for a raw bytes bytearray?

Tags: python-3.x, type-hinting, mypy

Due to a lack of better wording I used "raw-bytes" to denote `bytearray(b'\xDE\xAD\xBE\xEF')` as opposed to "none raw-bytes" being `bytearray(b'DEADBEEF')`.

I'm maintaining a codebase that does various byte manipulations on `bytearray()` parameters. In order for them to work properly they have to be "raw-bytes". A quick example why it matters:

```
raw_b = bytearray(b'\xde\xad\xbe\xef')
raw_b.reverse()
print(raw_b) -> bytearray(b'\xef\xbe\xad\xde')
```

is not the same as

```
b = bytearray(b'DEADBEEF')
b.reverse()
print(b) -> bytearray(b'FEEBDAED')
```

And there are many other things that go wrong like indexing values etc.

Both `raw_b` and `b` of the above example are of type `bytearray`, so typing on `bytes` isn't helping me. Functions that require these raw bytes currently have the following construct all over the place to ensure the parameter is actually in raw bytes

```
try:
    value = binascii.unhexlify(param)
except binascii.Error:
    #already raw bytes
    pass
```

How would I go about typing for raw-bytes so I can get rid of that junk?

Comment: It's not clear to me how the "non-raw" bytestrings are different. In all these cases, you have sequences of bytes.

Comment: You misunderstood; there is no raw bytes distinction. You used escape sequences in one, straight-up ASCII Letters in the other. They define entirely different values.

Comment: @MartijnPieters from your answer in the duplicate link: "bytes objects basically contain a sequence of integers in the range 0-255". If that's so then why does b'A' == 0x41 returns False? That signals to me it is not uint8 like you say. What am I missing in this logic?

Comment: @ixje `b'A'` is the full sequence, not an individual integer! `b'A'[0] == 0x41` is True and so is `b'A' == bytes([0x41])`.

Comment: My mind must be really stuck in classifying 1 character as a nibble and 2 as a byte when reading values associated with `byte(s)`. I see what you're saying now, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`b'DEADBEEF'` is a string of 8 bytes, they are not interpreted as hex values at all. It's as you wrote: `bytearray([0x44, 0x45, 0x41, 0x44, 0x42, 0x45, 0x45, 0x46])`.

`binascii.unhexlify()` in fact converts a string of ASCII hex digits to binary data.

The difference in how they are printed ('A' instead of '\x41') is because python print printable characters as characters, but represents them as escaped hex constants if not printable.

So `bytearray(b'\xde\xad\xbe\xef')` and `bytearray(b'DEADBEEF')` ARE two bytearrays but with different content - in particular `len()` of the first is `4`, of the second it's `8`.

Your codebase is working correctly with both, but you need to pass the correct data: I would avoid to embed `unhexlify()` allover your framework, but I would ensure that you pass the correct data to it.

Put in other words: you cannot pass `bytearray([0x44, 0x45, 0x41, 0x44, 0x42, 0x45, 0x45, 0x46])` in place of `bytearray([0xDE, 0xAD, 0xBE, 0xEF])` and expect the result be the same!

Comment: This does not answer the question. I know they're not the same, that's why the `binascii.unhexlify` stuff is in there and that's why I'm asking how differentiate upfront.

Comment: so what are you asking for? How can the library know that 0x44,0x45 must be kept the same or converted to 0xDE internally? That's a responsibility of the caller: the distinction between "raw-bytes" and "none raw-bytes" doesn't exist. The only distinction I see is in printable characters content. But I do not expect that a sufficient distinction for a library working on binary data... however it depends on you specific application: if it makes sense to you... than you have nothing to ask about it.